# Obtain group average for numerous groups that vary in size

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, countif, array-formulas

I get the feeling this is close to impossible, but here goes. I have data structured like this:

```
Test Group 1
pass
fail
pass
fall

Test Group 2
pass
fail

Test Group 3

pass 
fail
fail
pass
```

I want to be able to paste it into Excel and have Excel summarise the percentage of each test group. So it would end up looking like this:

```
Test Group 1               Percentage Pass: 50%
pass
fail
pass
fall

Test Group 2              Percentage Pass: 50%
pass
fail

Test Group 3              Percentage Pass: 50%

pass 
fail
fail
pass
```

BUT as you can see the test group length is not set, and it may vary. I was hoping is that I might be able to create a formula that follows this logic:

```
if( A<n> contains "Test")

count A<n> +1 until A<n> contains "Test"
```

It seems like I'm asking a lot from Excel formulas. I have spent some of today writing a small C# app that will split the configs into separate files so that I could copy and paste separate files into Excel. But it would be great to have fewer steps!

--- UPDATE ----

There were three very interesting approaches to this problem proving nothing is impossible :p

I wanted a solution that allowed me to copy and paste results in and see a load of percentages pop up so I was always sort of looking for a formula solution HOWEVER, please take the time to look at pnuts and Jerrys answers as they reveal some useful features of Excel!

chuffs answer was the one I was looking for and it worked out of the box. For anyone who wants to delve deep into how it works and why, I broke the formula down into steps and filled in some help information. The key to these formulas is combining MATCH, OFFSET and the slightly more obvious SEARCH / FIND / LEFT (I used to use IFERROR(FIND type approach, LEFT seems cleaner :) )

Do look at the documentation for these formulas but to see it all in action with some examples see the Google Spreadsheets I created detailing chuffs answer:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AqODI11eAjtldDhDd2dBcFhpZW9SXzEybGtMUWMwM3c#gid=0

---P.S---
For the record I did actually create a C++ program to prettify my data and ouput it as .csv files. If I had had this info I wouldn't have bothered but am glad I tried both routes, it was a fun learning adventure.

Comment: Do you want it in the format you mentioned above or is a table with each group and the percentage on the right okay?

Comment: @Jerry sorry for the late reply, I ended up getting caught up writing a c++ program do spit all this data out for me :p 

The format is very important, basically i am writing some scripts for a testing team where they get there output in something roughly similar to the above format (and it can't be outputed any other way), I wanted to minimize human error by creating a sheet they could copy and paste the data into and it do all the sums for them :)

Comment: Don't worry, that's fine ^^ Better late than never ;) And I'm glad you could find the solution you needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single, array-formula solution to this problem is possible. It requires only that a stop value "Test" be added at the bottom of your column of data.

Assuming your data are in the range `A2:A18`, here is the formula that would compute the average in cell `B2`:

```
  =IF(LEFT(A1,4)="Test",
      COUNTIF(OFFSET(A1,1,0,MATCH("Test*",$A2:$A$18,0)-1,1),"pass")
          / COUNTA(OFFSET(A1,1,0,MATCH("Test*",$A2:$A$18,0)-1,1)),
      "")
```

The key parts of the formula are expressions that calculate the ranges for the two count functions, `COUNTIF` and `COUNTA`.

The COUNTIF function - which counts the number of passes in a group - takes two arguments, the range for the count and the condition to be met by cells counted.

I use the `OFFSET` function to provide the count range. `OFFSET`takes five arguments:

- An anchor cell (if a range is provided, the function only uses the top left cell in the range).
- The number of rows below (+) or above (-) the anchor cell that the range to be returned will begin.
- The number of columns to the right (+) or left (-) of the anchor cell for the start of the return range.
- The number of rows to return.
- The number of columns to return.

For example, `OFFSET(A1,5,2,4,1)` will return the range `C6:D9`.

In the formula, the anchor cell is `A1`, the row offset is 1 and the column offset is 0, in other words, the start of the range to return is `A2`.

The number of rows to return is computed by the `MATCH` function. For the calculation of the average for the first test group, `MATCH` looks in the range `A2:A18` for the row of the first cell that starts with the word 'Test'. `A2` is the cell in the pass/fail column just below the cell that starts the test group.

The last cell in the column is `A18`, which has been added to the data and contains the word 'Test'. This prevents the formula from returning an error for the last test group. Otherwise, the match would return an error because it could not find another occurrence of `Test` beyond the start of the final group.

Also note that the anchor points for the match range, i.e., `$A2:$A$18`, leaves unanchored the row reference to the top of the range (the 2 in `A2`). That's so the range will adjust downward as the formula is copied down so as to find the next, not the previous, occurrence of 'Test'.

Finally, I decrease the number of return rows by 1 to exclude the `Text` that `MATCH` found, which belongs to the next group.

The `COUNTA` functions - which counts the total number of passes and fails in a group - uses the same OFFSET/MATCH expression to get the range for the group.

This is an array formula and so must be entered with the <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> key combination. Copy the formula down to the bottom of the data (excluding the cell with the 'Test' stop  value) to calculate the averages for each group.

For convenience, here is the formula without the breaks shown above. It can be directly pasted into the worksheet (remembering to confirm it with <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>).

```
  =IF(LEFT(A1,4)="Test",COUNTIF(OFFSET(A1,1,0,MATCH("Test*",$A2:$A$18,0)-1,1),"pass")/COUNTA(OFFSET(A1,1,0,MATCH("Test*",$A2:$A$18,0)-1,1)),"")
```

[image: spreadsheet result]

Comment: This is exactly the kind of thing i was looking for, i just tested the first function and it works exactly how i would expect! I am now taking the time to fully understand the solution!

Comment: Right this makes a lot of sense, i wish i knew about MATCH and OFFSET before! If i am not mistaken it doesn't have to be an array formula? in this case it worked without cntr+shift+enter

Comment: For everyone's conviencence I put the whole thing into google docs with a breaj down of the formulas:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AqODI11eAjtldDhDd2dBcFhpZW9SXzEybGtMUWMwM3c#gid=0

Comment: should mention, you have to finish with "test" otherwise your last result will be gibberish, see my spreadsheet

Comment: Also, google docs didnt seem to support "Test*" but excel did, so remember to adjust your formulas accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Basically Subtotal will meet the requirement, *provided* some fairly tedious layout adjustments are acceptable.

**Preparation:**
Assuming `Test Group 1` is in `A1`, insert Row1 and ColumnA, with  in `A2` `=IF(LEFT(B2,1)="T",B2,"")` and in `C2` `=IFERROR(MATCH(B2,{"fail","pass"},0)-1,"")` and both formulae copied down as required. (And change fall to fail in source!)

**Subtotal:**
Select `A:C`, Data > Outline – Subtotal, At each change in: `(1) Test Group 1`, Use function: `Average`, Add subtotal to: check (Column C), uncheck Summary below data, OK.

**Tidy up:**
 1. Move `A3:C3` to `A1` and `A2:C2` to `A3`.
 2. Filter `A:C` and for `ColumnB`, Text Filters, Contains add `Test`, OK.
 3. In `C3` put `="Percentage Pass:  "&C4*100&"%"` and copy down to last row numbered in blue (should show `#DIV/0!`).
 4. Highlight `A:C` for all the rows numbered in blue and embolden.
 5. Hide `ColumnA` and, optionally, hide or delete `Rows1:2`.
 6. Take off filter selection.

Hopefully with preparation as on the left the result would be similar to as shown on the right:

[image: SO16859574 first example]

---

*Example re comment to @Jerry's answer:*

[image: SO16859574 second example]

Comment: subtotal is an interesting function that I never knew about, it didnt work first try but it is useful to know about, thank you!

Comment: I got it to work thanks, it is defiantly in my armory from now on :)

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways to tackle this -- one possible easy solution is to add a column next to your pass/fail column that says (assuming column A):

`=IF(A1="pass",100,0)`

if you do that, then the average of those values would be equal to the percentage pass.

Comment: sorry I do not think you understood my question correctly, it is not about creating the percentage I can do that with =COUNTIF (which is better then the hidden column approach IMHO) its about counting the correct number of rows for each "group" which varies in number